# How to Update Cell Table Footer Dynamically

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I am trying to add footer to the celltable and finding hard time to change the celltable footer dynamically but i am able to add while creating columns like below

```
cellTable.addColumn(qty, "Qty",Integer.toString(totalQty));
```

This is not i am looking for,Is there any way to set footer to cell table dynamically.Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [Header](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Header.html) and add it to the column which should contain that footer. 
For example:

```
public class QuantityFooter extends Header<Number> {

    private final Number totalQty;

    public QuantityFooter(Number totalQty) {
        super(new NumberCell());
        this.totalQty = totalQty;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Number totalQty) {
        this.totalQty = totalQty;
    }

    @Override
    public Number getValue() {
        return totalQty;
    }
}
```

Then add it to the column:

```
QuantityFooter quantityFooter = new QuantityFooter(0);
cellTable.addColumn(qty, new TextHeader("Qty"),quantityFooter );
```

When you need to update the footer you just call `quantityFooter.setQuantity(10)` and you probably need to redraw the headers/footers with `redrawHeader()` and `redrawFooters()`